# How to manipulate the content of a MS Word compressed file format

Tags: ms-word, docx

I know that the microsoft docx file format is a compressed zip archive. I analyzed it and I think I understand that I can manipulate it by changing the content of the /word/document.xml file inside this file structure.

But after I zip the folder again and try to open it, MS-Word complains with a message like:

*"The file ... cannot be opened because its content is causing problems. "*

I wonder which is the correct method to zip the content of the xml files after manipulating? Or is there something like a checksum I have overseen?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why ms word complains about my manipulated docx format was, that the compressed file structure was within another folder, which I created to edit the document.xml file.

It is important that the xml files are located in the same root folder structure as in the original file.
A similar question has been asked on StackOverflow [here](https://superuser.com/questions/411911/re-zipped-docx-files-dont-open-in-word).